# Prove that $V$can not be a $S-space \mbox { single } $.

Tags: linear-algebra

Def

A subspace $W\mbox { of } V$ is called $S-invariant $  if for every element $T\mbox { of } S$ the vector $T \alpha \mbox { belongs to } W$ for all $\alpha \mbox { of } W$. It is said that $V$is $S-space \mbox { single }\mbox { if } V \ne \{0 \}$ and if the only subspaces 
$S -invariant$ of $V \mbox { are } V$ itself and the null subspace.

Problem:

Let $V$ a complex vector space of dimension $n> 1 \mbox { and } T$ nonzero operator over $V \mbox { and is } S = [T ] $. Prove that $V$can not be a $S-space \mbox { single } $.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks for everything :D Nice day or night :D

Comment: Your definition is quite mixed up. Where did $T$ come from? A subspace being $S$-invariant normally implies that $S$ is a linear operator. In that case what does "for every element $T$ of $S$" even mean? If this question means what I think it means, then you simply have to prove that the operator has an eigenvector.

Comment: My guess would be that $S$ is an algebra of operators, and that $[T]$ means $\Bbb C[T]$, the subalgebra of linear operators generated by a single operator. In the case $S$-stable and $S$-single reduce to $T$-stable and $T$-single (though there is something to prove there). But it is hard to be sure if the question is not formulated more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

because T have a eigenvalue ,so having a eigenvector $v$.\
the one dimension subspace generated by $v$
of $V$  is a $S-invariant$ obviously.
And the dimension of $V$ is $n>1$
so,$V$ cannot be $S-space$ invariant.